# Can I install rlwrap on windows? Or this is only for linux?

Tags: linux, windows, rlwrap

I can't find a guide to install on Windows.

https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap.

If installation on Windows is not possible, are there analogues for Windows?

Comment: If you install cygwin, you can build the tool yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rlwrap [README](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/blob/master/README.md) mentions:

> As it is often used with older or even obsolete software, rlwrap strives to compile and run on a fairly wide range of not necessarily recent Unix-like systems (FreeBSD, OSX, HP-UX, AIX, Solaris, QNX, cygwin, linux and probably quite a few more)

Windows in itself is not sufficiently Unix-like to be on that list, but `cygwin` (GPL), and, more recently WSL (free as in beer), provide a compatibility layer that allows you to install `rlwrap` (there are pre-packaged versions if you don't want to build from source) on a Windows machine.

That said, unlike the ususal Linux terminal emulators, the Windows console appears to have a history and line-editing mechanism built in that makes `rlwrap` a bit less necessary under Windows than on a Unix-like machine.

Keep in mind that `rlwrap` cannot wrap just any windows console app, but in general only unix-like programs, so you'll need `cygwin` or WSL anyway to have any use for it.